# How to remove routes only in child admin (SonataAdminBundle)?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have admin like "User  Admin" and one child admin like "Document Admin""

```
admin.users:
    class: App\Admin\UserAdmin
    arguments: [~, App\Entity\User, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD]
    calls:
      - [addChild, ['@admin.documents'] ]
    tags:
      - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Users}
    public: true

admin.documents:
    class: App\Admin\DocumentsAdmin
    arguments: [~, App\Entity\Document, ~]
    calls:
       - [setParentAssociationMapping, ['user']]
       - [setTranslationDomain, ['admin']]
    tags:
      - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Documents}
    public: true
```

And i try to remove create and delete route

App\Admin\DocumentAdmin

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{        
    parent::configureRoutes($collection);
    $collection->remove('delete');
    $collection->remove('create');
}
```

But when i open this admin (*/admin/app/user/1/document/list*), i receive error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route
>   "admin_app_user_document_create" as such route does not exist.").

Not working, but should be. I want to see child admin wit users documents without add and create buttons.

But when i open document admin directly ( */admin/app/document/list* )  - everything is ok! I see list without add and edit and delete button.

How to remove routes in DocumentAdmin for both situation ?

**Symfony 4 / Sonata Admin 3.35**

Answer (score 1):

You only removed the create and delete links. You need to remove the link to list the entity too. I guess this is what you need? Add this line too.

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{        
    parent::configureRoutes($collection);
    $collection->remove('delete');
    $collection->remove('create');
    $collection->remove('list');
}
```

You can see list documents because you did not remove the list action from route collection.

Comment: I want to see lest of documents in child admin. If i put your code - i will recive same error in child admin. But when i open list of documents directly - your code will work.The  main question is why in child admin that code not working

Answer (score 1):

Just do cache:clear it take time to regenerate routes

Comment: Hey ! Could you you explain why your solution would solve this issue ? :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's true, child routes are somehow super-cached in the admin.hasRoute validation because of this sonata still tries to generate create button with already removed route. clear:cache solved this to me, thanks